Short Film - Normal Doll vs. Barbie
Can anyone help me identify a short film (animated or puppets, I can't recall) that I saw only the end of several years back on TV Ontario?
When I tuned in, it was a doll and her children, but then Barbie shows up with Ken in a convertible and carries the kids off.  The doll then takes a screwdriver and disassembles herself, only to reappear in the last scene, smiling at the camera.
I know this is a long shot, but I thought I'd give it a try. 
Thanks!

Looks like a Full Moon film


Aria (2001)

This animated short by Pjotr Sapegin is inspired by Puccini's opera
  Madame Butterfly. The puppet Butterfly lives alone on an island, until
  a white ship brings the handsome sailor Pinkerton. They become
  passionate lovers. Eventually his ship leaves, and Butterfly waits
  longingly for her lover to return. She feels an ocean of life growing
  in her belly. The ocean swells, and a small, unprotected mussel washes
  up on the shores of her body. He soon grows into a beautiful child.
  But when Pinkerton finally returns, he tears away Butterfly's child,
  dashing all her hopes. Butterfly can only find comfort in death... but
  how is a puppet to die? (Synopsis from NFB.ca)

Watch the short here or at the NFB's (National Film Board of Canada) website.
